# Are the battery power and gain related in a digital mixer?

Tags: battery

I was using Sound devices772 recorder (without mixer) for pilot recording.I landed up loosing gain in the recorder when the battery went down.Does that happen with digital recorder?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask this question at Sound Devices corporation and let us know the results...

Answer (score 0):

If You use 48 V, 
Yes, because of insuring the mic gets enough voltage.

At least happened to me quite often.